# Arrow equivalent of mapM?

Tags: haskell, arrows

I'm trying to grok & work with Arrows, and am having some difficulty. I have a context where I need an `Arrow [a] [b]`, and I want to write an `Arrow a b` and map/sequence it inside the arrow, a la `mapM`. Specifically, the arrow is a Hakyll `Compiler`, but I don't think that matters much for the answer.

Given an arrow

```
myInnerArrow :: Arrow a => a b c
```

How can I lift this into an arrow

```
myOuterArrow :: Arrow a => a [b] [c]
```

?

I have scoured the base library, particularly in `Data.List` and `Control.Arrow`, but I cannot find anything that looks like it will do the job. Does it exist under a name I do not expect? Is it provided by some other library? Is it impossible to write for some reason?

Comment: Follow-up: Hakyll has a `mapCompiler` function.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't without choice.  The lifting function will have this type:

```
mapA :: (ArrowChoice a) => a b c -> a [b] [c]
```

The easiest way to implement is by using `proc` notation:

```
mapA c =
    proc xs' ->
        case xs' of
            [] -> returnA -< []
            (x:xs) -> uncurry (:) ^<< c *** mapA c -< (x, xs)
```

Untested code, but should work.  Note however that a function that generic is going to be really slow.  I recommend writing this mapping function for your arrow specifically.