# fmapping arrows over monads

Tags: haskell, arrows, category-abstractions

I understand that an Arrow is a Profunctor, where one can transform its input and its output, but can one map an arrow *over* a Functor?

I understand that as-asked the answer is "no", since the `fmap` function type signature is `(a -> b) -> f a -> f b` and does not admit `Arrow a b`, but I hope what I'm asking is clear.

I am looking for a way to, for example, transform a `Maybe` input with an Arrow, where `Nothing` goes to `Nothing` and `Just x` goes to `Just y` where `y` is the result of applying the Arrow to `x`.

Answer (score 7):

`Arrow` combines two concepts. One of them, as you say, is that of a profunctor, but first of all it's just a specific class of *categories* (as indeed the superclass evidences).

That's highly relevant for this question: yes, the signature of `fmap` is `(a -> b) -> f a -> f b`, but actually that is not nearly the full generality of what a functor can do! In maths, a functor is a mapping between two categories *C* and *D*, that assigns each arrow in *C* to an arrow in *D*. Arrows in different categories, that is! The standard `Functor` class merely captures the simplest special case, that of endofunctors in the **Hask** category.

The full general version of the functor class actually looks more like this (here my version [from constrained-categories](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.3.0.1/docs/Control-Functor-Constrained.html)):

```
class (Category r, Category t) => Functor f r t | f r -> t, f t -> r where
  fmap :: r a b -> t (f a) (f b)
```

Or, in pseudo-syntax,

```
class (Category (──>), Category (~>)) => Functor f (──>) (~>) where
  fmap :: (a ──> b) -> f a ~> f b
```

This can sure enough also work when one of the categories is a proper arrow rather than an ordinary function category. For instance, you could define

```
instance Functor Maybe (Kleisli [] (->)) (Kleisli [] (->)) where
  fmap (Kleisli f) = Kleisli mf
   where mf Nothing = [Nothing]
         mf (Just a) = Just <$> f a
```

to be used like

```
> runKleisli (fmap . Kleisli $ \i -> [0..i]) $ Nothing
[Nothing]
> runKleisli (fmap . Kleisli $ \i -> [0..i]) $ Just 4
[Just 0,Just 1,Just 2,Just 3,Just 4]
```

Not sure whether this would be useful for anything nontrivial, if using the standard profunctor-ish arrows. It is definitely useful in other categories which are *not* **Hask**-profunctors, [for instance](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/linearmap-category-0.3.2.0/docs/Math-LinearMap-Category.html#g:5)

```
instance (TensorSpace v) => Functor (Tensor s v) (LinearFunction s) (LinearFunction s)
```

expressing that you can map a linear function over a single factor of a tensor product (whereas it's generally not possible to map a nonlinear function over such a product – the result would depend on a choice of basis on the vector space).

Answer (score 4):

> I am looking for a way to, for example, transform a `Maybe` input with an arrow, where `Nothing` goes to `Nothing` and `Just x` goes to `Just y` where `y` is the result of applying the Arrow to `x`.

This can be implemented for specific `Functor`s (such as `Maybe`), though `ArrowChoice` will likely be necessary:

```
maybeAmap :: ArrowChoice p => p a b -> p (Maybe a) (Maybe b)
maybeAmap p =
    maybe (Left ()) Right
    ^>> returnA +++ p
    >>^ const Nothing ||| Just
```

See [*Arrow equivalent of mapM?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11303642/2751851) for a similar function written in proc-notation.

Speaking of `mapM`, *profunctors* has [an interesting class called `Traversing`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/profunctors-5.2/docs/Data-Profunctor-Traversing.html):

```
-- Abbreviated class definition:
class (Choice p, Strong p) => Traversing p where
  traverse' :: Traversable f => p a b -> p (f a) (f b)
  wander :: (forall f. Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> s -> f t) -> p a b -> p s t
```

The flag-bearer instance of `Traversing` is the one for the [`Star` profunctor](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/profunctors-5.2/docs/Data-Profunctor-Types.html#t:Star), which provides an alternative encoding of the familiar `traverse` function. Note that, while [leftaroundabout's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43431843/2751851) demonstrates a non-**Hask** functor for categories which are not necessarily **Hask**-profunctors, with `Traversing` we have a construction for `Profunctor`s that do not necessarily have a `Category` instance.